# Protect a folder by .htaccess RewriteRule to php

Tags: php, image, security, .htaccess

We are building an online photo-album. People need to login to see the images.We are trying to protect the image-files as well but we are stuck in a problem

By a session-variable we check if the users is logged in.

```
$_SESSION['is_ingelogd']
```

We build a security page (which checks if the user is logged in). We include this page to every page that has to be secured. But now we want to protect the images too.

So we build a .htaccess file that refers all requests of files in our photo-folder to a php page.
The php page has to check if the user is loged in.
If the user is not loged in, it will echo a text with the request to login.
If the user is logged in, the the php file has to to send the requested file (image).

We use the following code to do this:

*The .htaccess file (in the folder /fotoalbum/uploads/ ) :*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fotoalbum/
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !image\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !image\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ image.php [QSA,L]
```

*The .php file (in the folder /fotoalbum/ ) :*

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['is_ingelogd'] == "1") {
    $type = mime_content_type((string)$_SESSION['REQUEST_URI']);
    header("Content-type: ".$type);
    echo file_get_contents($_SESSION['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
} else{
    echo 'Please <a href="../login.php">login</a> to see this  
file.';
}

?>
```

This code works halves;
If a user is not loged in and tries to open any file of the folder /fotoalbum/uploads/ , the php  shows the request to login.

But if the user is logged in, we don't see the picture.
In IE9, the screen keeps blank and in FireFox 3.6, a png returns a message that the image can't be
displayed because it contains errors. a jpg returns the url of it and a txt file returns ï»¿

We build this scripts with help of following links:

- http://michael.theirwinfamily.net/articles/csshtml/protecting-images-using-php-and-htaccess
- http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1492222 (#post 12)

Thanks for any help

---

### **UPDATE:**

I did some prototyping and the return of `mime_content_type((string)$_SESSION['REQUEST_URI']);` seems to be blank/null.

*I placed following code in the php file:*

```
<?php
$serveruri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$fileuri = (string)('./uploads/'.basename($serveruri['path']).PHP_EOL);
$file = strval($fileuri);

echo 'URL Is: '.$file;  
echo '<br />type Is: '.mime_content_type((string)$file);
exit;
?>
```

The browser shows:

```
URL Is: ./uploads/test.jpg
Type Is:
```

You can see it doesn't echo a content type.
But when I set

`$file = './uploads/test.jpg';`

it perfectly returns:

```
URL Is: ./uploads/test.jpg
Type Is: image/jpeg
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: what does your "mim_content_type()" function return? according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php it is deprecated!

Comment: It's likely `mime_content_type()` isn't available in your php install. Use `function_exists()` to determine it. `fileinfo` is supposed to replace it, but I believe it's still just an extension.

Answer (score 1):

With many tips of this topic I made it work.
However it works now with a query string in the URL.

*.htaccess file in the folder fotoalbum/uploads/ :*

```
Options -Indexes
<Files *>
  deny from all
</Files>
```

*getfile.php file in the folder /fotoalbum/ :*

```
<?php

//this file checks if user is logged in and dies the request if the user is not logged in
include_once('./config.php');

$file = "uploads/" . $_GET['f'];
$type = mime_content_type($file);

header("Content-type:" .$type);
echo file_get_contents($file);

?>
```

To get an image (or whatever type of file), the url is `getfile.php?f=file.extension` (where file.extension is the file in the folder fotoalbum/uploads/ .

Thanks al lot everybody for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the PHP-File is saved with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark), save it without BOM.

Why i guess this: ï»¿ looks like a BOM

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle

txt files are working now in IE9 by this solution.
In FF 3.6 they are still not woring. Either the images don't work in IE and FF.

Comment: What is the complete response if it fails(you can determine it using firebug's network-tab)?

Comment: I reversed my -1 after your edit. Your answer wasn't helpful without an explanation for why you came to this conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
I'm taking a shot here, but have you checked to make sure mime_content_type is returning the correct mime type for your file? It would seem like if the statement

```
header("Content-type: ".$type);
```

is not outputting correctly, then the image or text file will not come through correctly either. PHP.net indicates that the mime_content_type function is deprecated, so you might want to try out the [finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) function.

Good Luck!

Comment: I did some prototyping and the return seems to be blank/null.

_I placed following code in the php file:_

`<?php
$serveruri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$fileuri = (string)('./uploads/'.basename($serveruri['path']).PHP_EOL);
$file = strval($fileuri);

echo 'URL Is: '.$file; 
echo '<br />type Is: '.mime_content_type((string)$file);
exit;
?>`

The browser shows:
`URL Is: ./uploads/test.jpg
Type Is: `

But when i set 
`$file = './uploads/test.jpg';`
it perfectly returns:
`URL Is: ./uploads/test.jpg
Type Is: image/jpeg`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should use readfile() instead of echo file_get_contents() when streaming images and other binary files back to the client.

**Update:**

The issue you are having with mime_content_type() is due to PHP_EOL which is adding a line break. There also is a lot of unnecessary type casting. Below is a cleaned up version that should work for you:

```
<?php
$serveruri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$file = basename($serveruri['path']);


echo 'URL Is: ' . $file;  
echo '<br />type Is: ' . mime_content_type($file);

exit();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks gcorne. But as you can see in my update; I can't even get a tge mime_content_type of the file, so that seems to be the (first) problem